# TypeError: Cannot read property 'channels' of undefined DISCORD

Tags: javascript, api, discord, bots

I get this error when I run this code and I can't figure it out why it is not working..

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'channels' of undefined
    at Request._callback (/Users/carlohera/Desktop/test.js:13:33)
```

Comment: What version of discord.js are you using? It seems you have conflicting functions from both v12 and v11

Comment: 12.3.1, please tell me how it needs to be.

Answer (score 0):

IDs of guilds and channels should be `Strings`, not `Numbers`.

```js
let guild = client.guilds.cache.get('700967388379742318');
let channel = guild.channels.cache.get('754993174954508308'); // also, make sure to use `cache.get`
```

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'channels' of undefined .....
same thing

Comment: What version of discord.js are you using?

Comment: lastest available on "npm install discord.js" - 12.3.1

Comment: Then your ID is just invalid.

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more?

Comment: It just means that your ID is wrong. Try double checking it to make sure you didn't accidentally delete a number or something.

Comment: Try running `console.log(client.guilds.cache.map(g => g.id))` and see what it returns

Answer (score -1):

Your variable guild seems not to be set and is null/undefined.
Maybe you should check if your client.guilds.cache.get has the correct syntax and if the parameter is the right one. Since guild is undefined your guild.channels.get causes the error.